# Anyway to change Keystore or Keystore's Info on android without publish new app

Tags: android, android-keystore

I need to change or upgrade my keystore to Trust Certificated Keystore(from trusted companies).

But I can't publish new app. Is there anyway to change mykeystore to Trusted Keystore??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to change your certificate for a published app, you **have** to re-publish to do that. It is explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

Comment: I remembered one of them now
Step 1: sign apk with old and new certificate together
Step 2: upload signed this apk
Step 3: sing apk with only new certificate.
Step 4: upload apk which signed with only new certificate  

This method worked before; but they blocked this.